# Using Delete and Select clause in one query

Tags: mysql

I have three tables .

```
circle
id   name 
1     first
2     two
3     three
4     four

user_circle

user_id  circle_id  user_type_id
1        1          1
1        2          1
1        3          1
1        4          2
2        2          2


user_type

id  type
1   admin
2   member
```

I want to delete the circle where user_id =1 and user_type_id =1 and number of user in that circle is one  . How can i do this in one query?

I need a result which will delete following circle from table .

```
circle_id
1
3
```

Comment: you can't delete the circle. You can only delete the row,

Comment: @Strawberry . I have edited my question. I want to delete the entry from circle  table , hitting query in user_circle .

Comment: So you want to delete rows with ids 1 & 3 from the circle table, but retain the equivalent rows within the user_circle table?

Comment: @Strawberry . circle_id in table user_circle   is foreign key  , referencing id  column in circle table . So if i get success in deleting these circles from circle table , it will delete the rows from   user_circle table as well .

Comment: You mean that an "ON DELETE CASCADE" referential constraint has previously been specified? This would be a lot easier to follow if you provided proper DDLs.

Answer (score 0):

First of all select `circle_id` having only one user. Then you have to make a subquery and alias it because you can't update a table you just selected from. At the end, use `DELETE` and apply all `WHERE` conditions you need.

```
DELETE FROM users WHERE circle_id IN (
  SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT circle_id FROM users GROUP BY circle_id HAVING (COUNT(user_id)=1)
    ) AS u
)
AND user_id = 1 AND user_type_id = 1
```

Comment: This is all a bit unnecessary though

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS user_circle;

CREATE TABLE user_circle 
(user_id  INT NOT NULL
,circle_id  INT NOT NULL
,user_type_id INT NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(user_id,circle_id)
);

INSERT INTO user_circle VALUES
(1        ,1          ,1),
(1        ,2          ,1),
(1        ,3          ,1),
(1        ,4          ,2),
(2        ,2          ,2);

SELECT * FROM user_circle;
+---------+-----------+--------------+
| user_id | circle_id | user_type_id |
+---------+-----------+--------------+
|       1 |         1 |            1 |
|       1 |         2 |            1 |
|       1 |         3 |            1 |
|       1 |         4 |            2 |
|       2 |         2 |            2 |
+---------+-----------+--------------+

SELECT DISTINCT x.* 
           FROM user_circle x 
           LEFT 
           JOIN user_circle y 
             ON y.circle_id = x.circle_id 
            AND y.user_id <> x.user_id 
          WHERE x.user_id = 1 
            AND x.user_type_id = 1 
            AND y.user_id IS NULL;
+---------+-----------+--------------+
| user_id | circle_id | user_type_id |
+---------+-----------+--------------+
|       1 |         1 |            1 |
|       1 |         3 |            1 |
+---------+-----------+--------------+

DELETE x 
  FROM user_circle x 
  LEFT 
  JOIN user_circle y 
    ON y.circle_id = x.circle_id 
   AND y.user_id <> x.user_id 
 WHERE x.user_id = 1 
   AND x.user_type_id = 1 
   AND y.user_id IS NULL;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)

SELECT * FROM user_circle;
+---------+-----------+--------------+
| user_id | circle_id | user_type_id |
+---------+-----------+--------------+
|       1 |         2 |            1 |
|       1 |         4 |            2 |
|       2 |         2 |            2 |
+---------+-----------+--------------+
```

Comment: Hi @Strawberry . Thank you for your answer . but i have updated my question . Can you plz now tell me , how should i delete entry from table circle , hitting query in user_circle with same conditions mentioned above ?

Comment: Do you see how I provided proper DDLs? You can do the same.